# How to execute curl from rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rest-client

Hi I am trying to create a payment module for my rails application with sum up. This is the rest api that they are providing I tried with RestClient but it is returing 400 bad request.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.sumup.com/token \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d 'grant_type=client_credentials'\
  -d 'client_id=**Client_ID**'\
  -d 'client_secret=**Client_Secret**'
```

This is what my restclient method looks like :

```
RestClient::Request.execute(
method: :post, 
url: "https://api.sumup.com/token",
data: "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=**CLIENT_ID**&client_secret=**Client_Secret**",
headers: { "Accept" => "application/json", "Content-Type" => "application/x-www-form-urlencode" }
)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to manually form encode the parameters which is a very likely source of errors.

```
RestClient.post(
  "https://api.sumup.com/token",
  {
     grant_type: "client_credentials"
     client_id: "**CLIENT_ID**"
     client_secret: "**Client_Secret**"
  },
  { 
    accept: "application/json", 
    content_type: "application/x-www-form-urlencode" 
  }
)
```